# Hardware for a pfSense router with 1000Mbps connection

Tags: pfsense

I have a 1000Mbps internet connection both up and down. And I'm thinking of upgrading my current config to a more robust and future proof configuration. Im thinking of the AES-NI support on the upcoming 2.5 pfSense version. I have been trying to wrap my head around pfSense, and I begin to understand that if your want to max throughput you need:

> Multiple cores at > 2.0GHz are required. Server class hardware with PCI-e network adapters. [docs](https://www.pfsense.org/hardware/)

I will probably have about 200 concurrent connections on different services behind the router, run suricata on OVPN on a few outgoing connections. And 1U case is necessary. Server hardware is a must (supermicro is cool).

I have been looking at the Intel Atom platform, for example the Supermicro motherboard model A1SRi-2758F, with Atom Processor C2758 TDP 20w, 2.40 Ghz, 4 mb cache, 8 cores and 8 threads. But I'm just no much of a router and hardware noob to tell if the Atom is enough.

## Atom:

- AES-NI support, check.
- Medium power consumption, check.
- Fits in 1U,check.

Any suggestions on hardware to build a pfSense router?